# Accessing class string returns NULL

Tags: java

This is a debug oriented question, but i've been very confused why some of my objects are returning NULL values.

I have a GUI here that takes strings from the text field when a button is clicked,

```
public class USAdditionalGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public String AreaCode; // declare Strings
public String Exchange;
public String LastFour;
public String State;

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // On button click use getText() to collect the strings from the 
    //`enter code here` fields and store them into the declared strings. 

    AreaCode = jTextField3.getText();
    Exchange = jTextField1.getText();
    LastFour = jTextField2.getText();
    State    = jTextField4.getText();

}
```

The next class has get methods for each of the String varibles, and here lies the problem, I create an object to the GUI class and try to access the String information but it keeps coming up NULL when I print it out.

```
public class TRFUSAddressFormatting{
private String State;
private String areacode; // 3 digits
private String digitExchange; // 3 
private String lastfour; // 4

USAdditionalGUI usobj = new USAdditionalGUI();

public String getState(){

    State = usobj.State;
    System.out.println(State); // Why does this print NULL!!?!?!
    return State;
}


}
```

Am I accessing the string correctly?

Comment: It seems you don't really understand when your methods are called. Add traces to the code, or use a debugger and put a breakpoint at the beginning of each method, to understand how your code works. When `getState()` is called, the button 1 has not been clicked yet, or it has been clicked on another USAdditionalGUI instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you declare strings, you need to initialize them or they will be null.

```
public class USAdditionalGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public String AreaCode = ""; // declare Strings
    public String Exchange = "";
    public String LastFour = "";
    public String State = "";
```

or whatever `DEFAULT` value you want to them

btw, I suggest you to declare them private and implement a get method to retrieve their information

```
public class USAdditionalGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private String AreaCode = ""; // declare Strings
    private String Exchange = "";
    private String LastFour = "";
    private String State = "";

    public String getAreaCode(){
         return AreaCode;
    }

    //and so
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't know that about strings in Java. I for sure will add the extra encapsulation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Variables/fields in your snippet ie, AreaCode, Exchange are instance variables of a class which are initialized to their default values when class's object is created. Objects' default value is null unless explictly initialized and primitives have their own default values like int -> 0 etc. Since Areacode, Exchange, LastFour, State above are of type String which are stored as objects on JVM Heap hence they are initiazed to null unless you explicitly initialize them yourself.